# varias tabelas em PL/SQL num Cursor

Tags: pl-sql

Preciso colocar o SELECT abaixo a funcionar dentro de um cursor, mas não estou a conseguir unir as 3 tabelas, alguém me pode ajudar?

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROFESSOR.NOME, ESTUDANTE.NOME
FROM PROFESSOR INNER JOIN SUPERVISIONA ON 
PROFESSOR.ID_PROF=SUPERVISIONA.ID_PROF INNER JOIN ESTUDANTE ON SUPERVISIONA.ID_EST=ESTUDANTE.ID_EST
WHERE ESTUDANTE.NOME='RITA'
```

Comment: Sem a definição das tabelas e especificar melhor o que acontece de errado fica um pouco difícil de dar algum palpite.

Answer (score 1):

Com base na pouca informação passada, acredito que sua query já está correta, a sugestão seria colocar um UPPER na cláusula ESTUDANTE.NOME pois você está passando a string 'RITA' mas pode ser que no banco esteja 'Rita'. Outra sugestão de query seria:

```
SELECT P.NOME NOME_PROFESSOR, E.NOME NOME_ESTUDANTE
FROM PROFESSOR P, ESTUDANTE E, SUPERVISIONA S
WHERE S.ID_PROF = P.ID_PROF
AND S.ID_EST = E.ID_EST
AND UPPER(E.NOME) = 'RITA';
```

**Isso levando em consideração que a tabela SUPERVISIONA tem os ids de PROFESSOR e ESTUDANTE.**

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já um exemplo de uma pl utilizando a query em um cursor, ficaria assim:

```
DECLARE

    v_nome_professor VARCHAR(30);
    v_nome_estudante VARCHAR(30);

    CURSOR C_TESTE IS
        SELECT P.NOME NOME_PROFESSOR, E.NOME NOME_ESTUDANTE
        FROM PROFESSOR P, ESTUDANTE E, SUPERVISIONA S
        WHERE S.ID_PROF = P.ID_PROF
        AND S.ID_EST = E.ID_EST
        AND UPPER(E.NOME) = 'RITA';
BEGIN
    FOR c IN C_TESTE
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            v_nome_professor := c.NOME_PROFESSOR;
            v_nome_estudante := c.NOME_ESTUDANTE;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Valores retornados:');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Professor: ' || v_nome_professor || ' / Estudante: ' || v_nome_estudante);

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nenhum dado encontrado!');
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]